# React: how to fire the parent component method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-bootstrap

How do I get access from component to the methods of the owner of this component?

I.e. (maybe) you need to get a pointer to the owner of the element and already call the method by the pointer.

For example:

component #1

```
class MyReport extends Component {
  my_method() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <MyReport>
        <MyElement />
      </MyReport>
    );
  }
}
```

and component #2

```
class MyElement extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    // GET METHOD my_method OF OWNER
    console.log(parent.my_method());
  }

  render() {
    return <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press</Button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: pass `my_method` as a prop, from the *parent* to the *child*, then you'll have access to it. It's the most basic concept in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking how to call a method of the parent you just pass it trough props of the child component:

Component #1

```js
class MyReport extends Component {

  my_method() {
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyReport>
        <MyElement methodFromParent={this.my_method}/>
      </MyReport>
    );
  }
}
```

Component #2

```js
class MyElement extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    // GET METHOD my_method OF OWNER
    console.log(this.props.methodFromParent);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Press</Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Although, you wrapping `MyElement` with `MyReport` seems like a mistake you made when writing this question.

Comment: this option is indeed a solution to my problem, but is it possible to do without an explicit indication of the owner? `<MyElement/>` instead of `<MyElement methodFromParent={this.my_method}/>`

Comment: Well in this case no. You can use High order component to wrap MyElement, but composition should always be your way of thinking. Nice point made here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html